# Azure DevOps self hosted agents in Docker container

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am following the tutorial located [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/docker?view=azure-devops). I am able to get a self hosted agent running in a Docker container. After the agent is running, I am able to run jobs on it in a pipeline only while the container is running. I would like to keep this docker container build agent running as a service, so I don't have to start it up for each time I am executing a pipeline. Any advice on how to configure a docker container build agent to keep running continuously would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

> I am able to run jobs on it in a pipeline only while the container is
> running.

Agent in Docker should be 'run as a service' by default, you need to make sure the container is running, otherwise, the agent will not run.